# add html class value with existing class in symfony2 form?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have defined some filed in my FormType and each form element has class value like below

```
 $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Name',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
        ));
```

in twig file wrote like this

```
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

This code generate output like this

```
 <input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' />
```

now I want to add extra class in this element like `error` class which generate following output

```
<input type='text' name='name' class='form-control error' />
```

For generating above output I wrote like code in Twig file-

```
{{ form_widget(form.name,{attr:('class'=>'error')}) }}
```

This code generate following output--

```
<input type='text' name='name' class='error' />
```

So I am confused, what should to get my expected result. Add extra class value to my form element in html.
My Expected output is

```
<input type='text' name='name' class='form-control error' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple classes inside the class attribute.

Like this:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Name',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control error'),
    ));
```

Comment: This is not the ans what I expected. You add error class static way but how to add this class dynamically. If I need this class I will add otherwise I don't need this class anymore

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comment on @Moshikaro's answer, you're probably going to have to use flow control to build up the class string, either in Twig or the Controller:

**Twig**

```
{% set errorClass = '' %}
{% if errorTest %}
    {% set extraClass = ' error' %}
{% endif %}
{{ form_widget(form.name,{attr:('class'=>'form-control'~errorClass)}) }}
```

or maybe

```
{% set errorClass = '' %}
{% if errorTest %}
{% extraClass = ' error' %}
{% endif %}
{{ form_widget(form.name,{attr:('class'=>form.config.attributes.class~errorClass)}) }}
```

**Controller**

```
$errorClass = "";
if ($test)
{
    $errorClass += " error";
}
$cssClasses = "form-control" + $errorClass;

$builder->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Name',
        'attr' => array('class' => $cssClasses),
    ));
```

You get the idea, anyway.  I've not been able to test any of that.